# How to use Xfig on high DPI screen?

Tags: x11, resolution, wayland, xfig

On a [high DPI](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89052/can-linux-deal-with-ultra-high-resolution-displays) screen, lines in Xfig are very thin. *Is it possible to scale the lines, or the entire Xfig UI?*

Note that I don't want to scale the entire desktop. Other application UIs are legible on high DPI screens.

Perhaps a Wayland compositor can scale an individual window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Method that I used in the end:

- Run Xfig in its own desktop under TigerVNC server.
- Connect to the VNC server with a VNC client that allows scaling.

To simplify the process, I created a tool to run arbitrary applications scaled up, [Vncdesk](https://github.com/feklee/vncdesk). A simple command such as `vncdesk 2` starts the server and connects a viewer. Closing the application or the viewer shuts down the VNC server:

[image: Screenshot showing original and scaled app]

An alternative could be running each application window in its own VNC viewer, which is the goal of experimental [`x11vnc -appscale`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11vnc).

Answer (score 1):

I'm now using an Apple 32-inch "Pro Display XDR" monitor on a macOS system with Xquartz in full resolution (starting it with full-screen mode enabled using `xrander -s 6016x3384`), and Xfig is one of the few apps that so far still refuses all attempts to get even its menu fonts to resize relative to the screen resolution.

However a quick and dirty hack on macOS with Xquartz in full-screen full-res mode is to open Xfig in the top-left corner of the full-res screen, then switch back to macOS (by exiting full-screen mode), then back to Xquartz again **but** without changing the resolution with `xrandr` (i.e. just use the shortcut or menu to turn full-screen back on).  Window decorations and window manager fonts will be scaled outrageously large of course, as now you can see just the top-left 1/4 of your Xquartz screen scaled to full-screen size, but you'll see Xfig clearly readable and usable in scaled mode.

This of course works for any application that is stuck in the dark ages of pixel-based layout and sizing.

Now if only macOS itself would run with the true full resolution of this display!